# Unable to select mulitple files using file input control while uploading on server

Tags: html, asp.net, input, file-upload

I am using the below file input code to select multiple files and upload to server.

```
<td class="value">
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" multiple="multiple" runat="server"></td>
```

I am able to select multiple files in local, but on server it doesn't allow me to select multiple files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "server it doesn't allow me to select multiple files" You select files locally and upload them to the server.

Comment: @VDWWD I have deployed my code onto IIS in windows server then the same code which is working locally, is not working in application post deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net file upload control as

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileImages" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
```

Comment: That is what OP has. `AllowMultiple="true"` will become `multiple="multiple"` in html.

Comment: @crack_iT Thanks for your answer, but i want solution with html input control only.

Comment: You must provide more information about the problem, like you are not able to select multiple files on webpage or you are not able to receive those files in server side code?

Comment: @crack_iT i am unable to select multiple files on webpage.

Comment: Then it must be client side problem and IMHO deploying on server should not make a difference. You can try to check what's the difference in your earlier(local) and current testing,  may be browser changed or upgraded or something lime that which can affect it

Comment: @crack_iT Yes, Exactly.. when i was trying with InPrivate mode in IE browser solution was not working, but If i test it normally solution is working. Not sure why the behavior is different with same IE browser.

Comment: I'm glad to know that it helped you to atleast narrow down your problem